# laravel 5.4: PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::configure()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am new to laravel. I am trying to use Snappy PDF from barryvdh. I have installed snappy pdf by following instruction from https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy. But when i run `php artisan serve` command following error is showed

PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::configure() in F:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel\doctorApp\vendor\barryvdh\laravel-snappy\src\LumenServiceProvider.php on line 21

Here is that line from my LumenServiceProvider.php:

```
public function register()
{
   $this->app->configure('snappy'); // line 21

   $configPath = __DIR__ . '/../config/snappy.php';
   $this->mergeConfigFrom($configPath, 'snappy');
}
```

I have installed wkhtmltopdf using this:

```
$ composer require h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64 0.12.x
$ composer require h4cc/wkhtmltoimage-amd64 0.12.x
```

in config/app.php i have added follwing lines in my providers and aliases:

in providers: `Barryvdh\Snappy\ServiceProvider::class,`

in aliases:

```
'PDF' => Barryvdh\Snappy\Facades\SnappyPdf::class,
'SnappyImage' => Barryvdh\Snappy\Facades\SnappyImage::class,
```

The path to the binaries in my config file (config/snappy.php): first one for pdf..

```
'binary' => base_path('vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64'),
```

2nd one for image...

```
'binary' => base_path('vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltoimage-amd64/bin/wkhtmltoimage-amd64'),
```

my bootstrap/app.php:

```
<?php

$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
);

/*snappy pdf start--- i added this part*/
class_alias('Barryvdh\Snappy\Facades\SnappyPdf', 'PDF');
$app->register(Barryvdh\Snappy\LumenServiceProvider::class);

//Optionally, add the facades like so:

class_alias(Barryvdh\Snappy\Facades\SnappyPdf::class, 'PDF');
class_alias(Barryvdh\Snappy\Facades\SnappyImage::class, 'SnappyImage');

/*snappy pdf end*/


$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class,
    App\Http\Kernel::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class,
    App\Console\Kernel::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
    App\Exceptions\Handler::class
);


return $app;
```

In my controller i added:

```
use Barryvdh\Snappy\Facades as PDF;
```

This is my controller:

```
public function PdfView(Request $request, $patient_id)
{
   $patients = Patient::where('id', $patient_id)->first();
   $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdfview', ['patients'=>$patients]);
   return $pdf->download('pdfview.pdf');

}
```

Can someone please say, why this error occurred and how to resolve this?

Comment: i did not use `configure` to begin with, that was by default in LumenServiceProvider.php.

Comment: i did not use `configure` to begin with, that was by default in LumenServiceProvider.php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Laravel you shouldn't use LumenServiceProvider but:

```
Barryvdh\Snappy\ServiceProvider::class,
```

as stated in package documentation

**EDIT**

Ok, I see the problem is different reading it again. You added:

```
class_alias('Barryvdh\Snappy\Facades\SnappyPdf', 'PDF');
$app->register(Barryvdh\Snappy\LumenServiceProvider::class);

//Optionally, add the facades like so:

class_alias(Barryvdh\Snappy\Facades\SnappyPdf::class, 'PDF');
class_alias(Barryvdh\Snappy\Facades\SnappyImage::class, 'SnappyImage');
```

into `bootstrap/app.php` but you shouldn't. This is for Lumen only, not for Laravel

Comment: I don't understand what you said. LumenServiceProvider was there by default when i update composer for snappy. Can you please explain what you just said @Marcin

Comment: Thank you :) @Marcin. One more thing, what shoud i use for `$pdf = PDF::loadView('pdfview', ['patients'=>$patients]);` in my controller. Because i used `use Barryvdh\Snappy\Facades as PDF;` in my controller, but it gives me FatalErrorException Barryvdh\Snappy\Facades not found.And if don't use `use Barryvdh\Snappy\Facades as PDF;` it gves me FatalErrorException Class 'App\Http\Controllers\PDF' not found. Please, help...

Comment: @NazemMahmud It's enough to add `use \PDF;` in your controller